# Changing field types and preserving existing data?

Tags: picklist

If I change a field from a picklist (single select) to a text field, will the existing data in that field be preserved?  I don't see that particular conversion on the list of [Notes on Changing Custom Field Types](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=notes_on_changing_custom_field_types.htm&language=en) as one that can lose data.  Can I assume it will convert without trouble?

My plan is to export any existing values just in case the conversion yields some unanticipated problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Simple answer is, **it will preserve data when you convert from picklist to text field.** If there is some risk Salesforce shows a alert message like following

[image]

Comment: Also, as mentioned, it would be a good idea to backup the data prior to the data type change.